# Xcode y error "ld: library not found for -lPods-FriendlyChatObjC" con CocoaPod

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Estoy siguiendo un ejercicio de un CodeLab de Google sobre [Firebase con Objective C](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat) que esta publicado en GitHub, y después de bajar el proyecto, instalar Cocoa y los **pod update** obtengo el siguiente error cuando abro por primera vez el proyecto con el Xcode:

ld: library not found for -lPods-FriendlyChatObjC
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Adjunto la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya hice clean y rebuild del proyecto, pero el error se mantiene. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Tal y como dice el usuario @Duukee debes abrir el fichero .xcworkspace que se genera al hacer pod install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¿Que archivo estás abriendo en Xcode?

Una vez que has instalado los pods con:

> `pod install`

se genera un archivo `NombreDelProyecto.xcworkspace`, el cual contiene tu proyecto (`NombreDelProyecto.xcproject`) y todos los pods de los que depende tu proyecto.
Debes de abrir dicho 'workspace' y compilar.